# Writing a given unitary in the same basis as the Hamiltonian (Operator Representation and Confusion)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, quantum-information, unitarity

I have a simple question concerning how to write the representation of operators, such as unitaries, using a specific order for the basis elements. Let me give you an example.

Consider a tripartite system (composed of qubits) with the Hamiltonian $H = |1\rangle \!\langle 1 |$. The total Hamiltonian, which is additive, is represented as
$$
H_{\textrm{tot}} = H\otimes I\otimes I + I\otimes H \otimes I + I\otimes I \otimes H.
$$
Without loss of generality, we can assume that the energies are arranged in ascending order, leading to:

$$H_{\textrm{tot}}= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

This matrix is represented using the convention that the sum of each element of the basis $|ijk \rangle := |i\rangle \otimes |j\rangle \otimes |k\rangle$ determines the energy in the block. For instance, block 1, $|000\rangle$, has an energy of $0+0+0 = 0$. Block 2 has an energy of 1, so the basis for this block comprises permutations of $|100\rangle$, and so on.

**My question is:** Assume that I want to construct a unitary operator that commutes with $H_{\textrm{tot}}$  whose action is given by:

\begin{align}
U|001\rangle = |010\rangle, \\
U|010\rangle = |001\rangle, \\
U|101\rangle = |110\rangle, \\
U|110\rangle = |011\rangle, \\
U|011\rangle = |101\rangle.
\end{align}

As before, I would construct such a unitary (which is block-diagonal) using the same basis elements that I used for the Hamiltonian. However, here's where I'm puzzled: both blocks with energies 1 and 2 have at least three different possible orderings. Which should I choose? For instance, using the convention:
$$
 (|000\rangle, |001\rangle, |010\rangle, |100\rangle, |011\rangle, |101\rangle, |110\rangle, |111\rangle) 
$$
I don't obtain the expected representation, which confuses me. I believe I have freedom to choose, but something is going wrong.

For example, I'm getting the following representation for $U$ (which is not correct according to what I should obtain):

$$
U = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: What are you expecting to obtain? What exactly is wrong? Are you sure the "correct" answer is using exactly the same convention as you?

Comment: Hi @BySymmetry, what would be the convention to write such a matrix? This is my question. I know it's not correct because I know the reduced states after the action of this unitary and the one I wrote doesn't take me to what I expect.

Comment: You can use any order that you want for the basis, as long as you're consistently using the same ordering when constructing the matrices.  There might be a standard in your particular (sub-)field, and there might be *convenient* choices sometimes that make computations easier (the quantum Fourier transform in Dirac notation somewhat comes to mind), but in the end, it doesn't matter.  You'll get the same *physical* results in the end.

Comment: "I don't obtain the expected representation": that means that wherever you get the "expected representation" from, they ordered the basis differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: You can choose any representation you want, and the one you chose is correct, as is the way you represented such a unitary matrix. Quantum mechanics doesn't prescribe a "correct" representation for states or operators, just as long as the representation is consistent.

**Not so short answer**: Typically, when using the Kronecker product (in languages such as Mathematica), it is standard to order the basis elements $|i,j,k\rangle$ in lexicographic order. For example, for three qubits, we would order the basis elements as:

$$|0,0,0\rangle, |0,0,1\rangle,|0,1,0\rangle, |0,1,1\rangle, |1,0,0\rangle, |1,0,1\rangle, |1,1,0\rangle, |1,1,1\rangle .$$

As a result, when representing the unitary transformation you provided as an example, we obtain the following matrix:

$$U=\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

This is equivalent to yours, as they are connected via a permutation matrix.

Comment: Ok, I understood! This was precisely what I was missing. When representing this matrix on Mathematica, I was getting a different representation.